# Validation fail with Passport and Json-WebToken

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, passport.js, axios

i learning `jwt` and `passport`, i am trying do a verification after login with corrects credentials, but it always return `401 Unauthorized`, i dont know why.

My code node.js that do generate the `jwt`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const _ = require("lodash");

const app = express();

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportJWT = require('passport-jwt');

const ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
const JwtStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

var jwtOptions = {}
jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
jwtOptions.secretOrKey = 'tasmanianDevil';

var strategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(jwt_payload, next) {
  console.log('payload received', jwt_payload);
  var user = users[_.findIndex(users, {
    id: jwt_payload.id
  })];
  if (user) {
    next(null, user);
  } else {
    next(null, false);
  }
});

passport.use(strategy);

var users = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'jonathanmh',
    password: '%2yx4'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test',
    password: 'test'
  }
];

app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  if (req.body.name && req.body.password) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var password = req.body.password;
  }
  var user = users[_.findIndex(users, {
    name: name
  })];
  if (!user) {
    res.status(401).json({
      message: "no such user found"
    });
  }

  if (password === user.password) {
    var payload = {
      id: req.body.id
    };
    var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
    res.send({
      message: "ok",
      token: token
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({
      message: "passwords did not match"
    });
  }
});
```

And my route protected:

```js
app.get('/pageOwnerAgency', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
  res.send({message: 'foi'})
});
```

What i understood was that the route above verify if there is the `jwt`. But it not working...

My component that do the ajax:

```js
 handleLogin = () => {
    axios.post('/login', { name: this.state.name, password: this.state.password })
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', res.data.token)
        window.location.reload();
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data.message))
  }
```

And my page ownerAgency that do the get to get the message:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/pageOwnerAgency')
    .then(res=>console.log(res.data.message))
    .then(error=>console.log(error))
  }
```

Somebody help me please?

Comment: Is there some client-side code that adds the jwt to the Authorization header for your axios requests?

Comment: Yes, i have added that line of code: `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('jwt')` but not working. :(

Comment: I think when you use `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')`, passport is expecting an Authorization header of the form `jwt {{token}}` as opposed to just the token by itself